# Laravel eloquent query to PostgreSQL DB for Yahoo Finance

Tags: postgresql, laravel, heroku, yahoo-finance, heroku-postgres

In my app I'm using torann/currency to fetch Yahoo Finance exchange rates. When using their official [documentation](http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-currency/doc/commands.html) adding and updating currencies works perfectly in Local development ENV, for which MySQL is used. 
App is deployed to Heroku, and there DB environment is PostgreSQL. So when I try to use `php artisan currency:manage add USD` , I get the following error: [invalid input syntax for integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkxIU.png)

DB Schema for that table is:

```
Schema::create($this->table_name, function ($table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('code', 10)->index();
            $table->string('symbol', 25);
            $table->string('format', 50);
            $table->string('exchange_rate');
            $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I tried everything that I could think of; tried to change all types in schema, tried to change blueprints etc. But either I get some different type of error, or I'm back where I started. Guessing that my lack of postgres knowledge is the main issue, and eventually I'll learn it, though I am hoping someone will know the answer to my q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-currency/issues/65) in the package's Database driver that assumes non-strict SQL behavior.

Comment: Followed your suggestion, but didn't manage to resolve the issue.
Though, thanks a lot that you've tried to help ^_^

Comment: What exactly did you do? The error in your screenshot is specifically due to the command trying to insert `''` into an integer column which is not a valid integer value.

Comment: I deleted 'id' column from $params. Maybee I misunderstood what I had to change?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you should not be changing code in your `/vendor` directory, that change should fix the error in your screenshot. Are you getting another error now?

Comment: I know that i shouldn't be changing it, made few backups just in case :D
Nope, same error.
This error only appears to happen on postgres. MySQL and Oracle12c are working perfectly.
I'll try few more things, before I write the whole damn thing myself (or at least try to write it) -- I've chosen torann because it saved me at least 10 hours of work.